# Debian 12 with XWayland: Problem with gnome-startup-applications and gnome-tweaks

Tags: debian, gnome, startup, wayland, autostart

After updating to Debian 12, `gnome-startup-applications`, and more generally, `gnome-tweaks` stopped working.

```
$ gnome-tweaks
WARNING: Shell not installed or running

(gnome-tweaks:19742): dconf-WARNING **: 08:17:46.684: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/app.py", line 50, in do_activate
    self.win = Window(self, model)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._model.load_tweaks(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakmodel.py", line 107, in load_tweaks
    mods = __import__("gtweak.tweaks", globals(), locals(), tweak_files, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 54, in <module>
    IgnoreLidSwitchTweak(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 28, in __init__
    GetterSetterSwitchTweak.__init__(self, _("Suspend when the laptop lid is closed"), **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/widgets.py", line 469, in __init__
    sw.set_active(self.get_active())
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 31, in get_active
    return not self._sync_inhibitor()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 42, in _sync_inhibitor
    bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SESSION, None)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: The connection is closed (18)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue as follows. In Debian, there is an option on the initial login screen, in the lower right corner, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Previously, in Debian 11, this option in the lower right corner displayed `Wayland` and `X11`. Now, in Debian 12, it shows `GNOME`, `GNOME Classic`, and `Openbox`. I switched to `GNOME Classic` and `Openbox`, which didn't work correctly. However, when I returned to `GNOME`, Tweaks started working again.